# Reputation Leagues ignore daily reputation cap and reputation loss due to deletion

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-leagues

The reputation leagues seem to ignore reputation loss due to post deletion. The reputation earned for the same post is counted though, in fact, it seems to ignore reputation capping.

---

Oliver has an impressive reputation league year 2012 score. It's a bit weird though that it's higher than his total rep — he didn't start out with *minus 1676* rep, did he?

> [image: less total rep than year rep]

I'm not sure what's going on here, but this seems to be mostly a result of the deletion of [this topic](https://superuser.com/q/432844) and the very high score answer by Oliver…

- if we ignore the deletion
- if we ignore daily reputation capping (as is shown in the moderator-only reputation stats)

  > [image: 1500 rep gained in two days!]

The June 2012 reputation league score of ~4300 rep seems indicates the same behavior, as it's the approximate sum of positive reputation changes in June recorded in the moderator-visible user profile (ignoring the deletion).

Comment: shouldn't this be on MSO?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Unless this has changed in the last few months, bug reports can be posted on all Meta sites.

Comment: true, but its probably not just a SU issue - its something that affects all sites. Then again, I commented and not vtmed since this isn't the 'wrong' place. Just wondering if there's a better option

Comment: @JourneymanGeek This bug report contains neither hand-drawn circles nor unicorns, and is thus unfit for MSO :-)